# Referencing cells in a different workbook using countif

Tags: excel, reference, external, criteria

I'm trying to use the **countif** function to count how many employees complete training late.  The required by date and all the completion dates are recorded on a separate workbook.

I know the usual forumula is `=countif(range, criteria)` and have no issues when I type an actual required by date for the criteria.  The issue has to do with referencing a cell in a seperate workbook.  The formula looks like `this:  =countif(xxxxG37:G158,>xxxxG5)` with xxxx being the location of the external workbook.
The formula works just fine when I put an actual date (i.e >xxxxG5 = 11/6/17).

The issue has to deal with how I"m referencing the criteria cell.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!  The data looks as follows:

```
G5  11/6/17

G37  11/2/17
G38  11/3/17
G39  11/9/17
G40  11/10/17
G41  11/1/17
```

G5 is the required by date.  G37-G41 are the completion dates.  I want to count how many of the dates are after 11/6/17.

Comment: A look at how your data is structured would be useful.

Comment: Yes.  I get the correct value if it's on the same sheet.

Comment: That was the issue.  I was missing the '&'.  I knew it was something simple like that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a typical syntax:

```
=COUNTIF([b.xlsx]Sheet1!$G$37:$G$41,">" & [b.xlsx]Sheet1!$G$35)
```

[image]

where the formula appears in another workbook *(a.xlsx)*